# How to remove color bar in seaborn heatmap?

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

How can I hide the color bar from a seaborn generated heatmap

```py
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)

ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `cbar=False` for that

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cbar=False)
```

I am answering my own question because I only came across the answer in a comment here [Matplotlib - How to remove color bar but keep the heatmap position unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50454360/2160809)
More details here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html